# Jquery post function works, but fails when duplicated

Tags: php, jquery, post

I came on here a few days ago with a problem, they got it to work. However, when I go to duplicate it, it fails. Leaving me very confused.

Here is the jquery

```
function loadSubCats(value)
{
    $.post("load_sub_cats.php",{ "catid": value },
            function(data) {
        $('#sub_categories').html(data);
    });
}
function loadSubCatsB(value)
{
    $.post("load_sub_catsb.php",{ "catidb": value },
            function(data) {
        $('#sub_categoriesb').html(data);
    });
}
```

I have the form select fields (1 in the file, 1 in load_sub_cats.php)

```
  echo"<select name='cselect2' onChange='loadSubCatsb(this.value)'  class='e1'><option value='0'>Please Select Location</option>";
```

Now to explain the issue, when I select a value from the main select, the second select appears fine. BUT when i select form that it appears the third isn't appearing (or even being called). I have the jquery in the parent file along with both of the div's. I have tried including these in the subfiles but same issue. I just can't seem to call the third page.

Comment: Your html is malformatted. echo"<select name='cselect2' onChange='loadSubCatsB(this.value)'  class='e1'><option value='0'>Please Select Location</option>";

Comment: Sorry this was an error when i was posting here i didn't copy/paste its already fixed in the actual file, still not working.

Comment: @MichaelClarke - Why would you not copy/paste the **actual** code? Please take more care to make your question correct in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that javascript user-defined functions are case-sensitive. You have -

```
function loadSubCatsB
```

but calling -

```
onChange='loadSubCatsb(this.value)'
```

Try changing to -

```
onChange='loadSubCatsB(this.value)'
```

Comment: Thankyou very much been staring at this for hours and didnt even notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Your php echo is incorrect formated!

Try this instead:

```
echo '<select name="cselect2" onChange="loadSubCatsb(this.value)"  class="e1"><option value="0">Please Select Location</option></select>';
```

Comment: this was an error when i tried posting here, the actual code was correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onChange, try using jQuery's `live` functions. ie:

Instead of:

```
onChange='loadSubCatsb(this.value)
```

Use this in your $().ready or equivalent function:

```
$('.e1').on('change', function() {
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    loadSubCatsB(newVal);
});
```

Comment: Made this change but no change, it does product a new error saying newValue has no value but prior to this there was no errors in the console.